# AngularJs: Passing search criteria from very large search form to service - create custom model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app with a very large search form (around 45 inputs) and I'm struggling trying to figure out how to best code this up in AngularJS.  I've just begun working with Angular, so this may be obvious, but I'm a bit stumped.  I'm not sure how to pass around the values entered into the form with my service being in an injected factory.

Here's the structure I currently have:

```
app.js - app module
search.js - search controller
datacontext.js - service factory
search.html - search form view
```

There is a Search function in the datacontext that runs the search service call:

```
    function Search(searchForm) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var requestParameters = {
            UserId: 1234,
            IpAddress: '127.0.0.1',
            QuickSearch: true
        };

        var request = {
            SearchParameters: searchForm,
            RequestParameters: requestParameters
        };

        $http.post(url, request)
            .success(function (data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
    }
```

To make that function easier to manage I am just passing in a search object, which contains all of the properties of a search - firstName, lastName, dob, etc.  When I call this function from the search controller, can I just pass in the $scope from the form (i.e. ng-click='RunSearch($scope)')?

One other requirement for this is that I need to count the number of criteria being passed in when the user clicks the search button to prevent searches with no criteria from being run.  Not sure how to implement that in the viewmodel...  Any tips from those who've done this kind of app before that might help point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path with the search object.  That way when you create your form, you can just bind each field to a property on the search object.

As for passing the scope from the form (i.e. ng-click='RunSearch($scope)'), no, you wouldn't want to do that.  In the view, the "$scope" is implied.  So you would just want to pass in the search object (ng-click='RunSearch(searchObject)') or rely on the fact that RunSearch is in the same controller and so it already has access to the search object by just looking on the scope (ng-click='RunSearch()' with RunSearch() being on the same scope).  It's probably a better practice to pass in the search object.

As for the form validation, I would have the RunSearch function do a traverse of the search object looking for a valid search term.  If none is found, then RunSearch could just set the $invalid flag on the form and then return false.  Then in the view, you could have an error message linked to that invalid flag to tell the user they must enter at least one search term.

Something like this:

```
<form name="searchform">
  <input ng-model="searchObject.firstName" type="text">
  <input ng-model="searchObject.lastName" type="text">

  <button ng-click="RunSearch(searchObject)">Save</button>
  <span ng-show="!searchform.$invalid">You must enter at least 1 search term</span>
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.RunSearch = function(searchObject) {
  if(!checkSearchObject(searchObject)) {
    $scope.searchform.$invalid = true;
    return false;
  }
  else performSearch(searchObject)
}
```